# Enum type conversion to int

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am trying to use the following code...
The Enum class i am using is

```
public enum AccountType {
        kAccountTypeAsset(0x1000),
        kAccountTypeAssetFixed(0x1010),

        private int value;
        private AccountType(int value)
        {
         this.value = value;    
        }
        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public AccountType accountType = kAccountTypeAsset;
        integerToDB(accountType);
...

/*************************/

public Object integerToDB (Integer i ) 
    {
    if(i == -1)
    {
        return null;
    }
     return i;
    }
```

How can i use

> accountType

as integer.

Comment: isn't that what your getValue() method is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`integerToDB(accountType.getValue());` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your enum has implemented a `getValue` method, you can use `accountType.getValue()` to get the integer value stored in `accountType`.